# DropDownList how to set DataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

Hi I have a DropDownList.

I need visualize in it a SINGLE value (ListItem) the current Logged in User, like

```
<asp:ListItem>Joe</asp:ListItem>
```

Here my wrong code, if the UserName is "Joe", the DropDownList visualize for every single letter an ListItem:
Example:

```
<asp:ListItem>J</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>o</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>e</asp:ListItem>
```

This is my code:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="uxUserListSelector" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>

        MembershipUser myCurrentUser = Membership.GetUser();
        myUserList.DataSource = myCurrentUser.UserName;
        myUserList.DataBind();
```

Any idea how to fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're setting the `DataSource` to a string (`myCurrentUser.UserName`), so it's interpreting that as an array of characters and binding to it accordingly.

As for how to fix it, what exactly are you trying to do?  Why are you using a `DropDownList` to display a single item?  Why not a `TextBox` or a `Label`?

For now, I'm assuming that you want the `DropDownList` to contain *all* of the users, and to pre-select the current user.  Is this correct?  If so, then you'll need a method to get the names of all of the users and bind the `DropDownList` to that list of names.  (A simple `IList<string>` of user names will probably do, but if you want more control over the `DataTextItem` and `DataValueItem` then an `IList<>` of a custom object may be better.)

Once it's bound to the *list* of usernames, you can set the selected value to the current username.

**Edit:** Based on your response, the overall code would look something like this:

```
// You'll need a method to get all of the users, this one is just for illustration
myUserList.DataSource = userRepository.GetAllUsers();
// Set this to the property on the user object which contains the username, to display in the dropdownlist
myUserList.DataTextField = "Username";
// Set this to the property on the user object which contains the user's unique ID, to be the value of the dropdownlist (this might also be the username)
myUserList.DataValueField = "UserID";
myUserList.DataBind();
// There are a number of different ways to pre-select a value, this is one
myUserList.Items.FindByText(myCurrentUser.UserName).Selected = true;
```

You will, of course, want to wrap some of this in proper error handling.  For example, the last line will throw an exception if the supplied username is not found in the list.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your thoughts, I need "pre-select the current user" the dropdownlist. could you post a simple example of code.. I am a beginner :-) thnaks

Comment: I really appreciate your help now is working thanks once again :-)